# Getting 400 error when trying to send an azure service bus message with broker properties

Tags: python, azure, azureservicebus

I have small python app that sends information to my azure service bus. I've noticed that each message has "broker_properties" dictionary and there is a property named "Label" that I can access later on from the service bus.

I am trying to send my message populating that property:

```
properties = {"Label":label}
msg = Message(bytes(messagebody, "utf-8"), bus_service, broker_properties=properties)
bus_service.send_queue_message("queue", msg)
```

But this doesn't seem to work. When the command above is executed I get back an error from Azure:

```
The value '{'Label': 'testtest'}' of the HTTP header 'BrokerProperties' is invalid.
```

Is this a bug in Python Azure SDK or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Looks like. .NET client has Nooooo issue with the Label property.

Comment: In the v7 of servicebus https://pypi.org/project/azure-servicebus/7.0.0/#description
you should be able to send a dict as application_properties using the `ServiceBusMessage`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your code, the issue was caused by using a Python dict object as the value of the `broker_properties`, but the `broker_properties` value should be a json string. Please refer to the test [code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/azure-servicebus/tests/test_servicebus_servicebus.py#L367) in Azure SDK for Python on GitHub.

So please modified your code as below.

```
properties = '{"Label": "%s"}' % label
```

Or

```
import json
properties = json.dumps({"Label":label})
```

Comment: For closure, issue was also opened on the Azure SDK for Python issue tracker and solved as Peter Pan said. https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/890

Comment: @LaurentMazuel Thanks for your feedback.